# Helm/Kube Error: query: failed to query with labels: stream error

Tags: go, kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-helm, helm3

Anyone faced similar issue with helm, even with helm list I get that

query: failed to query with labels: stream error when reading response body, may be caused by closed connection. Please retry. Original error: stream error: stream ID 3; INTERNAL_ERROR; received from peer

Comment: hard to tell without details, but either connection to API endpoint is broken, or ApiServer itself has an issue talking to etcd

Comment: @rkosegi - Thanks for the quick reply, you are totally right, It's the apiserver latency, I need to troubleshoot it but for now I just increased the timeout.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I found that it was a timeout issues.

Below are the ways I debuged and fixed the issue.

debug

```
helm ls --debug
```

delete older versions

```
kubectl get secrets --all-namespace | grep -i <name of your helm chart>
kubectl delete secret <name here>
```

Workaround: I increased the timeout and this helped for now:

```
helm install <name> <folder> --wait --timeout 10m0s --debug
```

I believe the root cause of this issue is with the apiserver throttle which, I need to check more to find the root cause for slowness.